# Is it possible to disable the battery entirely on my Lenovo laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop, repair

I have Lenovo 30-15IKB (Ideapad) laptop and my battery is internal. I want to disable the battery.

I tried to disable it by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> but it doesn't work.

I tried to do it from the BIOS but I didn't find disable built in battery option!

If there is no way to do it from the BIOS, is there a way to do it from the my OS or system?

Comment: Laptops are not designed to run without a battery. The charger is not powerful enough to cope with full loads. It is designed to charge the battery, which then powers the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure (90%) that you cannot disable the only battery.

If you wish to run with AC connected most or all of the time, use Lenovo Vantage (Microsoft Store) to set the Battery threshold value to a max of 80% and a min of 75 or 70%.  That is best for "always plugged in" battery health.

Once the battery is between 78 and 80% and says "Not charging", you can leave it plugged in. I have two such machines in this state.

If the battery is dead or near dead you need to replace it.